# Dimensions of image objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I would like to know how to retrieve the dimensions of an image with objective-c.  I have searched google and the documentation with no success, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you remember our discussion over my answer to your previous question? You will become a much better developer by working on your research skills - particularly patience when searching the documentation. That's not a slap but "sage advice I wish I had at your age." :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSImage` has a [`size`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000344-size) method, returning an `NSSize` struct containing the width and height of the image, or `{0, 0}` if the size couldn't be determined.

```
NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];

NSSize dimensions = [image size];

NSLog (@"Width: %lf, height: %lf", (double) dimensions.width, (double) dimensions.height);
```

#### Edit:

I have placed explicit casts to `double` because on some systems (64-bit especially) the `width` and `height` members may not be `float` types but `double`, and we would be providing the wrong types to `NSLog`. A `double` can represent more values than `float`, so we can cast *up* with a bit more safety.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try this shortly.

Comment: Floats are always cast to doubles when passed to variadic functions, so there’s no need to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

In iOS, `UIImage` has a `size` property, which returns a `CGSize`.

In OS X, `NSImage` has a `size` method which returns an `NSSize`. It also has a `representations` property, which returns an `NSArray` of `NSImageRep` objects. `NSImageRep` has a `size` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `size` method is correct for a size in points. Sometimes you need the pixel dimensions rather than the nominal size, in which case you must select an image rep (`NSImage`s can have several) and query its `pixelsWide` and `pixelsHigh` properties. (Alternatively, load images using `CGImage` and use `CGImageGetWidth()` and `CGImageGetHeight()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the NSString+FastImageSize category from the *Additions* section in https://github.com/danielgindi/drunken-danger-zone

I've only recently written it, and it seems to work fine.

This code will actually open the file and check the headers for dimensions (= it is really really fast), and supports PNG,JPG,GIF and BMP. Although I really hope you don't use BMP on a mobile device...

Enjoy!